# Android device goes offline

Tags: android-studio

I am using my Samsung galaxy Android device to run programs from Android Studio. And also I am a beginner. My device goes offline mode frequent times when I try to run my program.

For me this is a boring experience. How to fix this problem?

I want my Android device online always.

Comment: Do you have any kind of screen lock on your phone or a broken cable?

Comment: Yes. I have pattern lock activated on my device.Should I deactivate it ?

Comment: One problem could be that it goes offline after a specified time when your screen gets locked. Can you try to deactive it or increase the time for aut lock.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Problem solved.

Comment: Perfect, can you mark the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be that it goes offline after a specified time when your screen gets locked. Can you try to deactive it or increase the time for automatic lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your screen sleeps while debuging you can go to 
Settings-->developer Options --> StayAwake